# Can this javascript code be written elegantly?

Tags: html, slice, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Can some one help me to write this code elegantly as I am new to javascript. I am adding this to wordpress so I tried jquery already and for some reason it doesn't work so I tried this approach which is working but I don't like the way it's written.

If someone could help me to write in a better way that would be great. Thanks!

```
var par01 = document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[0].innerHTML;
var par02 = document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[1].innerHTML;
var par03 = document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[2].innerHTML;
var slicedPar01 = par01.slice(0, -17);
var slicedPar02 = par02.slice(0, -17);
var slicedPar03 = par03.slice(0, -17);
 document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[0].innerHTML = slicedPar01;
 document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[1].innerHTML = slicedPar02;
 document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt")[2].innerHTML = slicedPar03;
```

Comment: get the reference to the element once, instead of multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

I would just loop through the excerpts then you are not hard-coding for only 3 excerpts exactly:

```js
var home = document.getElementById("tt-insights-home");
var excerpts = home.getElementsByClassName("excerpt");

for (i = 0; i < excerpts.length; i++) {
  excerpts[i].innerHTML = excerpts[i].innerHTML.slice(0, -17);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is neat exactly what I wanted.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's could be like below:

```
var excerptElement = document.getElementById("tt-insights-home").getElementsByClassName("excerpt");

excerptElement[0].innerHTML = excerptElement[0].innerHTML.slice(0, -17);
excerptElement[1].innerHTML = excerptElement[1].innerHTML.slice(0, -17);
excerptElement[2].innerHTML = excerptElement[2].innerHTML.slice(0, -17);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small variation on a theme perhaps - not tested btw but looks OK.

```
let insights=document.getElementById( 'tt-insights-home' )
Array.from( insights.querySelectorAll('excerpt') ).foreach( node =>{
    node.textContent=node.textContent.slice(0,-17)
})
```